Sieve of Eratosthenes in OCaml
As an exercise I've implemented a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes in OCaml. It does require OCaml 5.2.0 or later as I've utilized Dynarray to handle my array of known primes.
I've designed the function to yield a sequence of prime numbers so that it doesn't need an upper limit specified and doesn't need to calculate further than required until requested by the consumer of the sequence.
It has passed all of the tests I've thrown at it, but suggestions for improvement are welcome.
let prime_seq ?(block_size=1024) () =
  let known_primes = Dynarray.create () in
  let offset = ref 0 in
  let sieve = Array.make block_size true in 

  sieve.(0) <- false;
  sieve.(1) <- false;

  let[@inline] incr_offset () =
    offset := !offset + block_size
  in

  let[@inline] reset_sieve () =
    Array.(
      fill sieve 0 (length sieve) true
    )
  in

  let[@inline] update_sieve_from_known_primes () =
    known_primes |> Dynarray.iter (fun kp -> 
      Seq.(
        ints 2
        |> map (( * ) kp) 
        |> drop_while (( > ) !offset) 
        |> take_while (( >= ) (!offset + block_size - 1))
        |> iter (fun m -> sieve.(m - !offset) <- false)
      )
    )
  in

  let rec aux n () =
    if n >= !offset + block_size then (
      incr_offset ();
      reset_sieve ();
      update_sieve_from_known_primes ();
      aux n ()
    )  
    else if sieve.(n - !offset) then (
      Dynarray.add_last known_primes n;
      Seq.(
        ints 2
        |> map (( * ) n)
        |> take_while (( >= ) (!offset + block_size - 1))
        |> iter (fun m -> sieve.(m - !offset) <- false)
      );
      Seq.Cons (n, aux (n + 1))
    )
    else
      aux (n + 1) ()
  in

  aux 0

